# Creating new shortcut in notepad++

Tags: button, notepad++, shortcut

I am trying to add a shortcut or a button in notepad++ to call an external program on the file I am currently editing.

For example, let's say I have the program "`analyzer.jar`". I would like to create a button (or shortcut) in notepad++ that would directly run the command "`cmd -K java -jar analyzer.jar "$(FULL_CURRENT_PATH)`".

Since I haven't found any solution yet, any help would be deeply appreciated :).

Answer (score 8):

Well, in fact I found how easy it is to create a shortcut for a command:

1. Go in the menu and select "<kbd>Run</kbd> → <kbd>Run...</kbd>" (or press <kbd>f5</kbd>)
2. Type your command
3. Click on "<kbd>Save</kbd>", and select the keyboard shortcut of your choice

Sometimes, when you look for complicated solutions, you don't see the simple ones...