# Add a new command to notepad++

Tags: open-source, notepad++

Notepad++ is my go to editor for most things. I would like to develop a new command(keyboard shortcut) for doing something unique. Anybody has any pointers regarding how I can do this?

I would like to create a command which arranges selected text in certain order based on the characters found. I would also like create a keyboard shortcut for running the same command.

Comment: Have you tried downloading the source-code? Please try to ask specific questions if you want meaningful assistance.

Comment: Possible answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6621811/2081889

Comment: Yes, In fact I am looking at the Notepad++ python script plugin also.

Comment: The problem with that post is it requires me to have a predefined command, in my case I want to write a new command.

Comment: Could you perhaps elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? Be specific, and I'm sure we'll be able to help.

Comment: I would like to create a command which arranges selected text in certain order based on the characters found. I would also like create a keyboard shortcut for running the same command.

Comment: Since you want to operate on specific parts of a file currently open in Notepad++, you're probably going to have to either find a plugin developed to do what you want, or develop one yourself.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41232/discussion-between-rjadhav-and-daemon)

Answer (score 1):

You have several options:

- develop a macro - examine **Macros** dropdown menu in Notepad++
- use **[AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com)** which can send keystrokes/mouseclicks, run apps/DLL's, work with clipboard, read any system settings, take values from input boxes and many more. Please see here [for its sample usage with Notepad++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22220666/in-notepad-change-tab-size-instantly/22880354#22880354)
- use JN plugin for Notepad++ and script your functionality in JavaScript - [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17430523/can-we-decode-url-with-nodepad). Similarly, there is a Python scripting plugin, too.
- write your own N++ plugin. You get the best control, but without experience this is the most difficult option.